# Boot-repair issue with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, windows-7, lightdm, aptitude

My VPS works absolutely fine but has had a few issues with booting since I upgraded it to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04. It will not boot after being switched off. So I Googled the problem and it looked like I should install and run `boot-repair`, so I did that in my putty connection.

I got this:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: SCreenshot]

Because of all the GTKs I checked out `lightdm` and found that it was stopped and wouldn't start:

`service lightdm status` gave `lightdm stop/waiting`

`service lightdm start` gave `start: job failed to start`

So I then ran `apt-get install aptitude` then `aptitude reinstall lightdm`. That all seems to run fine and dandy with no error messages. But the `service...` commands above give the exact same results.

This is beyond my current knowledge a bit so I was hoping someone could help me understand the error messages better - am I required to run `boot-repair` in a desktop environment instead of an SSH connection like putty?